# Getting two query string parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code below to get query parameters for a search in javascript. Is there any particular reason why this wouldn't be able to handle multiple parameters? I seem to be having trouble implementing it.

```
var params = [], hash;
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
if(q != undefined){
    q = q.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
        hash = q[i].split('=');
        params.push(hash[1]);
        params[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean multiple? What is an example URL that would not work?

Comment: @epascarello he means example.com/index.html?param1=foo&param2=data

Comment: @LeoWilson got it right.

Comment: @SteveHalla As far as I can tell, it works fine with LeoWilson's url

Comment: Based on the last statement of your for loop, it seems like params should be an object, rather than an array.

Comment: Why would you both `push` it **and** store it using a property/key? That's the part that makes the least sense.

Comment: params should be an object, makes no sense to push.

Comment: @PeterB could you suggest how to improve the code? What lines to remove/add?

Comment: check it out! i hope this could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use a regex to get the params.

```js
var test = 'example.com/index.html?param1=foo&param2=data#icouldhaveahashtoo';
var params = {};

test.replace(/[?&]([^=]+)[=]([^&#]+)/g, function(match, key, value){
  params[key] = value;
  return '';
});

console.log(params);
```

Comment: If you replace test's value w/ document.URL, this would be a perfect solution.

Comment: @LeoWilson I did that and this worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Tapiar can you help me with handling periods, asterisks and quotation marks?

Answer (score -1):

Seems your code works fine, however, it won't work properly with URL's with query parameters assigned more than one value (like `http://example.com/page.php?param=foo&param=bar`). Additionally, if one of the query string parameter names is `length` or something, that could do bad things to the `params` array - might be better to try a different container.

```
var params = [], hash;
var q = 'example.com/index.html?param1=foo&param2=data'.split('?')[1];
if(q != undefined){
    q = q.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
        hash = q[i].split('=');
        params.push(hash[1]);
        params[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
}

console.dir(params); // Array[2] 0: "foo" 1: "data" length: 2 param1: "foo" param2: "data" __proto__: Array[0]
```

---

I'd suggest having the `params` variable be an object, and skip the line `params.push(hash[1])`, because you can iterate over the properties using a `for..in` loop easily enough, and the order of the parameters shouldn't matter anyways. If there's more than one value for a parameter of a particular name, then the value of that parameter would be an array. For example, `?param=foo&param=bar` would end up being parsed as `{ param: ["foo", "bar"] }`.

Comment: Could you suggest some improvements?

Comment: @SteveHalla You mentioned you were having trouble implementing the code. It would help if you could go into more detail, otherwise, we're all grasping at straws.